Access denied when updating spip website with spip_loader.php
I am trying to update my SPIP website from SPIP 4.2 to 4.3, with spip_loader.php v6. When I access

https://www.adressedevotresite.net/spip_loader.php

I obtain a "access denied" ("accès refusé") despite being connected as an administrator. How can I solve this?

To use spip_loader.php, you must be connected as the administrator with ID 1 (see the list of authors and webmasters in Edit/Edition). If you cannot connect as webmaster 1 because it does not exist anymore, you may place a file named spip_loader_config.php at the root of your website. This file should contain a list of authorised webmasters that include your current ID, for example webmasters ID 2 and 12.
<?php

return [
   'authorized.users' => [2, 12],
];

